parsing json into rows in Python pandas dataframe
I have a pandas df as



user
dates




a
{"2024-05-16": -167}


b
{"2024-03-28": -104, "2024-04-12": -108}



Desired output



user
date
value




a
"2024-05-16"
-167


b
"2024-03-28"
-104


b
"2024-04-12"
-108



Basically, I want to each key in the json string to be in one row as 'date' and value in another column 'value'.
Thanks!

You can use this approach:
# assuming `dates` has string values, expand them to dict with `json.loads`
# otherwise, you can skip this and just use `df["dates"]` as an argument to `pd.json_normalize` instead
dates_expanded = pd.json_normalize(df["dates"].apply(json.loads))

# join user column with dates, melt to long format, drop nulls, and reset index
out = (
    df[["user"]]
    .join(dates_expanded)
    .melt(id_vars="user", var_name="date", value_name="value")
    .dropna()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

  user        date  value
0    a  2024-05-16 -167.0
1    b  2024-03-28 -104.0
2    b  2024-04-12 -108.0

